# Problema carregar arquivo CSS Sass

Tags: css, sass, gulp

Estou enfrentando um problema onde ao gerar o arquivo CSS, onde este é gerado por uma tarefa feita através do Gulp.
Ao interpretar o Sass e gerar o CSS, o arquivo no site só altera se eu excluir e criar um novo arquivo .css, fora isso ele continua o mesmo, sem as alterações que fiz.

Em arquivos CSS, criados na mão, as alterações são realizadas.

Algo parecido com um cache, mas, somente para os feitos a partir do Sass.

Já alterei o nome do arquivo e continuo com esse "cache".

Agradeço a ajuda.

segue meu arquivo gulpfile

```
`'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var sassOptions = {
errLogToConsole: true,
outputStyle: 'expanded'
};

gulp.task('sass', function() {
return gulp.src('./assets/sass/**/*.scss')
.pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
});

//Watch task
gulp.task('default',function() {
gulp.watch('assets/sass/**/*.scss',['sass']);
});`
```

Comment: Quando vc roda `$ gulp sass`, fora da *task* `watch`, o que acontece?

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira Acontece o mesmo, não atualiza o arquivo css no navegador.